# Why I have a 302 redirect after changing SSL certificate?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, gitlab

I have a VPS with Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I installed GitLab with different sites served by Apache2.  The GitLab version is Omnibus package 7.14.1.

I had successfully configured GitLab with HTTPS and with a self-signed certificate for testing (say it's with **olddomain.com**).  I bought a wildcard SSL certificate (for ***.newdomain.io**) and installed it for other websites served by Apache and they work perfectly.

For GitLab the story is a little different.  I searched for all references to **gitlab.olddomain.com** and changed them for **gitlab.newdomain.io**.  So in the file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` the change is:

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.newdomain.io:2443'
```

That's the only setting changed, the other are left with their default values.

The configuration of Apache is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gitlab.newdomain.io
    Redirect / https://gitlab.newdomain.io/

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab/access.log combined
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/gitlab/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

With the config for the HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName gitlab.newdomain.io

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/newdomain.io.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/newdomain.io.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:2443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:2443/

    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab/access.log combined
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/gitlab/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

After the changes I made the `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and even the `gitlab-ctl restart`.  For Apache, the `service apache2 reload` has been executed.

When I look into Chrome's **Developer Tools > Network**, I see the **Request URL** to **https://gitlab.newdomain.io**, the **Status Code** is **302** and **Location** is **https://gitlab.olddomain.com**.  The interesting thing is **Server: nginx**.  The **Remote address** is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443, but the service listening the port is supposed to be Apache2.

Running `netstat` I see those two lines:

```
tcp6  0  0 :::443          :::*          LISTEN      1849/apache2
tcp   0  0 0.0.0.0:2443    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      32493/nginx
```

Both DNS records for **gitlab.olddomain.com** and **gitlab.newdomain.io** are pointing to the same machine.  When I check the certificate in the browser, I have the *good* certificate, the wildcard one of **newdomain.io**, but I'm visiting the wrong domain.

Browser cache has been cleared, server restarted, etc.

Comment: Because nginx is sending the redirect?

Comment: Maybe it might seem a newbie question, but why nginx is sending a redirect, should it be Apache supposed to respond to port 443?  nginx is configured to port 2443 on this machine, as the netstat command is showing.

Comment: Take a look at your Apache configuration. It is obvious why nginx is responding to the request.

Comment: Well it's the ReverseProxy yes, but the question is why a redirect?

Comment: Go back to my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your Gitlab configuration, I already had too.

Within Gitlab you have a config for "startpage". This is the page you are redirected to, when you are currently not signed in.
So go to https://gitlab.newdomain.io/users/sign_in log in and change this setting in the adminpanel under settings.